# how to avoid countdown timer reset on page refresh , node js / socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

server.js

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var addedUser = false;

  socket.on('setTimer', function(data) {
    timer.setEndTime(data.time);
    socket.broadcast.emit('currentEndTime', {time: timer.getEndTime() });
  });
  });
```

client.js

```
$(function() {

    var timer = new Timer(),
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('currentEndTime', function (data) {
    //this is the full date time in ms.
    timer.setEndTimeFromServer(data.time);
});

 set = setInterval(function(){
  $('.time').trigger('click');
   clearInterval(set);
  },100);

   $('.time').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var time = $(this).text() * 1000;
    timer.setEndTime(time);
    timer.timeRemaining();
        socket.emit('setTimer', { time: time });
    });
});
```

Hi there, i am trying to integrate countdown timer for node js/socket io application. Timer works fine, but how do i avoid timer reset on new socket connection/page refresh. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This is because of two things:

1. Your socket goes away when you hit the refresh button and a new one is created and thus your connection to the server (and hence the timer value) goes away when you hit the refresh button.
2. When you load the page first, you don't get the current value of the timer and print it on your page to start everything.

You can have each individual timer stored in a key value storage. You can use the IP Address as key and timer value as value or something like that. This way, you can retrieve the current value of the timer for the user when user connects to the server and continue counting down.

If you use the socket ID as key, it will do you no good except to pointlessly populate a key value storage and spike up your memory usage. Use something more persistent, such as IP Address, username, e-mail or something of that sort as key and current value of timer as value.

Also, your current solution is flawed because it faces the "refresh lag". When you hit the refresh button, you stop counting for the amount of time that is spent on re-rendering of your web page. If it's nothing more than a handful of milliseconds, you're fine; but as long as it goes to a few hundreds of milliseconds, this will make actual difference. Do the count down at the server side. Just notify the client at the set intervals. This will increase the server workload, but at least you're not bound to having bad timers.

If you're going to have a single countdown, like "x days, x hours, x minutes, x seconds remaining to Superbowl or some other big event", you're much better off without socket.io. Just send the timestamp to the big event to the client and do the remainder on the client side.